# How to format DateTime columns in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datetime, datagridview

I'm using a DataGridView with object data binding to display information about logging entities in a system, retrieved via SOAP from a remote service.
One of the columns is called "Last action" and means the last time the entity logged a message. It is a `System.DateTime` value. When I read the SOAP response (example below), he timestamp obviously contains all the information, up to second fractions.

```
<LoggingEntity>
<host>marty86ce</host>
<process>10148</process>
<logger>http_core</logger>
<appName>httpd</appName>
<ffda>true</ffda>
<lastAction>2010-10-27T12:00:19.5117509Z</lastAction>
<lastHeartbeat>0001-01-01T00:00:00</lastHeartbeat>
<channelId>em_9BA2A2B4D0B6E66</channelId>
<ffdaChannelId>em_E7C8D1D4DE8EEB9</ffdaChannelId>
</LoggingEntity>
```

When I display it on the table, I instead can read up to the minutes
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLYBz.png]
I use the following code to do the data binding when I press the refresh button

```
public void RefreshEntities()
{
    IEntityManagement management = EntityPlugin.GetProxy();
    LoggingEntity[] result = management.FindLoggingEntities(new TemplateQuery { ffdaSpecified = true, ffda = true }); //Remote invocation

    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { gridEntities.DataSource = result; })); //THIS does the data binding from the array

    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { btnRefresh.Enabled = true; }));
}
```

I would like to know how to control column formatting of data bound values. I think that the format dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm comes from my system's settings. **How to override formatting settings programmatically?**

Thank you in advance

Full solution code on [Subversion](http://logbus-ng.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/logbus-ng/trunk/) (FFDAGui program) for the Logbus-ng open source project.

Comment: How to do this in WPF?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If it is a windows form Datagrid, you could use the below code to format the datetime for a column

```
dataGrid.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

**EDIT :**

Apart from this, if you need the datetime in AM/PM format, you could use the below code

```
dataGrid.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
```

Comment: What if you don't know which column may or may not contain a datetime? Like a dynamic query tool. How would you dynamically match a date entry and change how it gets formatted?

Comment: Format does not show up for DefaultCellStyle in intellisense.

Answer (score 45):

Use [Column.DefaultCellStyle.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) property or set it [in designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95y5fz2x.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.CELLSTYLEDIALOG%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)

Answer (score 30):

You can set the format you want:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
this.date.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle;
// date being a System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

Comment: `dd/MM/yyyy` formats the date as `dd-MM-yyyy`. Use `dd'/'MM'/'yyyy` to format the date as `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: `yourColumn.DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Format = "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy hh:mm:ss" };`

Comment: Unfortunately it isnt changing anything for me. My date stays as it is. Looks like the date in my column is treated as a string which makes it non-formatable. Are there special requirements to the dates apart from the point, that they are real date-values?

Comment: Even for me it does not work, I tried all the ways mentioned here. I'm using BindingSource!

Comment: im sorry, what is your `dataGridViewCellStyle` ?

Answer (score 2):

I used these code Hope it could help

```
dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item[2].ToString();
dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(item[2].ToString()).ToString("d");
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Comment: This is if you are manually populating the rows, and it is desirable for you to convert the DateTime to a String. The ToString("d") specifies the date only format from the DateTime ToString method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the format in aspx, just add the property "DateFormatString" in your BoundField.

```
DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}"
```

Comment: There is no such DateFormatString property in `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell`

Answer (score 1):

Published by Microsoft in [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings):

```
dataGrid.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d"; // Short date
```

That should format the date according to the person's location settings.

This is part of Microsoft's larger collection of [Formatting Types in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types).

Answer (score 0):

```
string stringtodate = ((DateTime)row.Cells[4].Value).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
textBox9.Text = stringtodate;
```

Comment: Could you please explain why and how this solves the issue?

Comment: Should rather set the format string when data binding the column.