# Change the datetime display format on datagridview date column

Tags: c#, sql, database

I want to change the default format(`MM/dd/yyyy`) of the datetime in the database table to (`dd/MM/yyyy`) when select and write the date with (`dd/MM/yyyy`) on the datagridview's date column.

Below is my code to convert string input date for instance: `24/4/201`3 to datetime and then convert to 
`4/24/2013` using query and select records from database.

```
   string date = this.ToolStripTextBox2.Text;
   DateTime dtDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/M/yyyy", null);
```

Query: FillByDate

```
   SELECT Record_ID, Grade, Type, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(Date AS DATETIME), 103) AS Date 
   FROM RecordsTable
   WHERE Date >= CONVERT(datetime, @fromDate, 105) 
   AND Date <= CONVERT(datetime, @toDate, 105)
   ORDER BY Date ASC
```

But it give this error;

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store
>   <24/04/2013> in Date Column.  Expected type is DateTime."

I know that the CONVERT part was wrong as if I remove the convert part out,
the date column can be written but in `4/24/2013` format.
I have no idea how to correct it. Anyone can help?
Thanks

Comment: You can use SET DATEFORMAT DMY to specify the date format in your FillByDate query

Comment: It was a tableadapter query. Can you further explain how to use SET DATEFORMAT DMY on tableadapter query? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string date = this.ToolStripTextBox2.Text;
   DateTime dtDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Try this code

Comment: it gives "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." when i entered date like 24/4/2013..it was not a correct format.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on this thread.
[How to format DateTime columns in DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033113/how-to-format-datetime-columns-in-datagridview?rq=1)

just set the default cell style in the designer.
I am sorry that i ask this kind of question before further searching.
Thanks