# How to get only date from DateTime Field of Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: c#, datetime, sharepoint

I am trying to get data from a sharepoint list which contains a DateTime Column. When I am binding this list data to a grid, the bound field for this DateTime Column is giving values in this format: **7/1/2014 12:00:00 AM**. I have put the DateTime Column as "**Date only**" but still getting the same. This is not the behavior I wish to have...I need only the date to come in my grid. Can someone please kindly suggest how I can achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you..

Comment: How are you binding the grid, which control are you using to bind? If you are using gridview you can refer this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033113/how-to-format-datetime-columns-in-datagridview

Comment: Thank you Kiran for your quick response and help. Yes I am using a gridview and this link served my purpose like a charm. Thanks again... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get *Only Date* from DateTime field of SharePoint with following code:

```
string date = Convert.ToDateTime(item["DateColumn1"].ToString()).ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Thanks For the response Ronak..! Marking it as answer as this would help someone looking for the answer in future.