# How to show the complete DateTime value in a Datagridview cell when it is exactly midnight?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a column that holds DateTime values like this:

[image: wild DataGridView named dgView]

The problem is in the selected row: it actually has the value "10/07/2015 12:00:00 am" but in the datagridview it is shown only "10/07/2015". 
The next row has the value of "10/07/2015 12:00:26 am". This problem happens only when the hour of the DateTime values is exactly midnight. 
When I pass that value to a textBox (to the left) with the following code, DateTime value is shown correctly (DateTime values are in the column with index 2):

```
text1.Text = dgView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

How can I make my DataGridView to show the complete DateTime values?
I do not want to set the [DefaultCellStyle.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4033113/111110) value because I want to show the DateTimes in the format of the OS regional settings (in my case is es-pe).

I'm targeting .Net 3.5 compiled for x86.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify the `DefaultCellStyle.Format`, but use a ["standard format"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) which will localize appropriately:

```
DefaultCellStyle.Format = "g"; // General date, short time pattern
```

I don't *know* that that will format midnight "fully", but it's worth a try.

Comment: I used "G" instead of "g" and It worked! and It doesn't override the regional settings (tested wiith es-pe and es-es) I'll write another answer to show how to do it from the VS designer

Comment: @Broken_Window, "G" and "g" are different format patterns.

Comment: @Fabio: I suspect it's just that Broken_Window wanted the longer time format.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right, I wanted the longer format.

Answer (score 1):

How to force the DataGridView to show hours exactly at midnight (this answer comes from Jon Skeet's Answer):

In Visual Studio (I'm using VS Express 2013) select your DataGridView, go to Properties->DefaultCellStyle, enter "G" in the Format property and click Ok or Aceptar (mine is in spanish):

[image]

This solved my problem, and it respects OS regional settings.

Can I fangirl a little?
OMYGOSHOMYGOSHOMYGOSHOMYGOSH Jon Skeet himself answered my question, yay! 
:D :D :D :D