# How to transfer date data from datagridview to datetimepicker in c# windows application

Tags: c#, datagridview, datetimepicker

I'm working on datagridview in c# windows forms application and I'm loading the data from the database,Now i want to edit the cell value and save the value to the database,
Here i have date and time in my database.

[image]

when i click the row header in datagridview the data are transfer to the text boxes and also in datetime picker

[image]

data are copy in textbox correctly but it gives error message when copy in datetimepicker.

code i done.

```
private void dgvpbx_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            txtname.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            cmbidentifier.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtplace.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            txtcity.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            dtpdate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            dtptime.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
        }
```

Error message is

[image]

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: yes but i could no get any thing

Comment: Extract the datagrid value as String to a new variable first, and debug through to check exactly what that value is. Also, if you know the exact format, consider using `DateTime.ParseExact(string, format, cultureinfo)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the exact format in which the date and time will be in the grid, parse them accordingly:

```
dtpdate.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
    "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dtptime.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
    "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

From the screenshot, your two `DateTimePicker` controls do seem to both give a full date, though. You might want to change those so one only picks time and the other only picks a date.

Do make sure that to put your dates and times *into* the grid, you convert the DateTime objects to string using exactly the same format:

(where `i` is the index you're currently editing)

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = dtpdate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = dtptime.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Please help me sir i got another error Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. on same line .

Comment: As I already said in the comments above, put the result  of the `.Value.ToString()` operation in a string variable and check what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

```
dtpdate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
dtptime.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

Comment: That won't work... the values in the grid are _strings_, not `DateTime`; that's the whole point here. You can't do string.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"). Otherwise you wouldn't _need_ any converting.

Comment: what is <<dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value>> in debug mode with breakpoint

Comment: Given the fact _all_ objects put into gridviews and similar controls just revert to their default .ToString() notation, the two can't be actual DateTimes, or they would look the same and give full date and time. So they're clearly just strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976306/how-to-show-the-complete-datetime-value-in-a-datagridview-cell-when-it-is-exactl

Comment: A possible solution is `dtpdate.Value = ((DateTime)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5]);`

Comment: @AlperŞaldırak Oh, it has formatters? Interesting. Still, if the objects _are_ `DateTime`, the whole converting mess is completely unneeded.

Comment: @raidensan Surely `DateTimePicker` expects a `DateTime` as value, not a string?

Comment: @raidensan Right. I didn't consider the value inside the grid could already _be_ a `DateTime`. I was unaware the control had formatters for things like that :-\

Comment: @Nyerguds it is not `DateTime`, it is an `Object`. So, if you know the type of cell you can employ Casting.

Comment: @raidensan I did mean the actual object inside the variable, yes. I know the `.Value` itself is `Object`.