# getting data between two Longdates c# MS access database

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Hi guys when I insert dates by longdate using `Datetimepicker` ex: `wednesday, April 26,2017` then I want to search between two dates but it can not give me all the dates between ?

Insert code

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Table1] ( [Employee Name],[Date],[Hours] ) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
```

search between Codes :

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table1 where [Date] between '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "' ";
```

Comment: Creating commands this way is not very secure. "....Text" could be anything.

Comment: use parameters , do not rush the query directly with value in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting `DateTime` as `string` and aslo trying fetch data using strings as filter for between.

So, few things:

- make sure your column `Date` is of type Date and not string.
- use `dateTimePicker1.Value` instead of `Text` because `Value` returns `DateTime` object.
- use parameters in your SQL commands

To sum things:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Table1] ( [Employee Name],[Date],[Hours] ) values (?, ? , ?)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeName", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Hours", textBox2.Text);



cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table1 where [Date] between ? AND ?";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateFrom", dateTimePicker1.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateTo", dateTimePicker2.Value);
```

Comment: thanks Bro search is good now but when I insert my long date to my table it now show the days name sunday and monday did I have to do some thing in my access table  but actually in my C# form I can see days name

Comment: format your code for display the way you want. For example, like this: i            `label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();` or `label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm;`

Comment: but I want days name also like Sunday monday

Comment: It is important to know that date is completely (with all elements, includin milliseconds) written in database. To Show it, you have to format it the way you want. Take a look at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). You need something like `label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("D");` or `label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()`

Comment: thanks Bro I inserted the date longdate and I can see it in my table as 
Saturday, April 01, 2017 and I canged my date table to long date now the problem is that when I call it to my data gridview not show the date like this : 
Saturday, April 01, 2017  it show 18/5/2017 in datagridview

Comment: show your DataGridView code. It's probably, as @Dmitry Egorov said, format. You should set `DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D" to your `DateTime` columns.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use parameters because right now your code is vulnerable to sql injection. So do this this way:

```
cmd.CommandText = ("insert_questions @store_result, @store_title, 
                    @store_des");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@store_result", store_result);
```

More reading : [Sql command parameters](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06)

And use dateTimePicker1.Value instead of text that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters to avoid date values being converted from strings:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Table1] ( [Employee Name],[Date],[Hours] ) values (@empName, @date, @hours)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empName", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hours", textBox2.Text);

// ...................

cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table1 where [Date] between @startDate AND @endDate ";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", dateTimePicker1.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", dateTimePicker2.Value);
```

Comment: I did it but I get this warning

Comment: Warning 2 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection.Add(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value).  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202' c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\AbsentSchedule\AbsentSchedule\Form2.cs 31 17 AbsentSchedule
 and inserted date like this 2017-04-27 00:00:00

Comment: I changed date in my access table now data is inserted as longdate but in showing it in my datagridview show dates like this 18/5/2017

Comment: [Set up `DefaultCellStyle.Format` property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38726576/4295017) of the date column to the desired format

Comment: thanks a lot Mr.Dmitry Egorov it works very good it show  me like that    Thursday, April 27, 2017    Saturday, April 01, 2017  Saturday, April 29, 2017 now I have to sort it ascending right ? to sort it from beginning of the month to end

Comment: Add `order by` clause to your query: `cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table1 where [Date] between @startDate AND @endDate order by [Date]";`

Comment: thanks its done by                 cmd.CommandText = "select * from [Table1] ORDER BY Date ASC";