# SqlDateTime Overflow Error When Button is Clicked

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, buttonclick

When I execute the application, the application runs... then when I click the button I'm getting the error

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this, as most of the solutions on the internet don't seem to work for me. Is this something that is on the SQL side?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlcn1 = new SqlConnection("My Connection String");
    sqlcn1.Open();

    //Stored Procedure
    SqlCommand sqlcmddel = new SqlCommand("My_Stored_Procedure", sqlcn1);
    sqlcmddel.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlcmddel.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sqlcn1 = new SqlConnection("My Connection String");
    sqlcn1.Open();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmdins = new SqlCommand("My_Stored_Procedure", sqlcn1);

        sqlcmdins.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //Stored Procedure
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@sugnum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt64 (row.Cells[0].Value);
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@sugtype", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@buyerid", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Convert.ToString (row.Cells[2].Value);
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@duedate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime (row.Cells[3].Value);
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@xrelqty", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDouble (row.Cells[4].Value);
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@purchasingfactor", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDouble (row.Cells[5].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the DateTime value that you are trying to enter into sql?

Comment: I'm trying to get the values that are in a SQL table

Comment: I'm guessing that `row.Cells[3].Value` doesn't contain what you think it contains!

Comment: as @ChrisDunaway said, that error that you are getting typically indicates that the value is either not a correctly formatted DateTime or it isn't a DateTime at all.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Haha would you look at that...It's showing up as, "M/DD/YYY  HH:MM:SS" in my Cells[3]... What is the solution to solving this problem now?

Comment: If the value is already in the sql database you can open SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and right click on the table in question. Then click "Edit Top ### Rows". You can then manually change the value.

If multiple values are incorrect then consider checking the design of the table to make sure the format is correct. You would right click the table and select "Design" to make sure that the column is using the correct data type.

Comment: @sudsy1002 Okay so on the SQL side of things I looked and the dates are in the correct format in the table already "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.00".... They're getting put into the datagridview in a different format "M/DD/YYY HH:MM:SS". Why is this?

Comment: This will likely be what you need.
 [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033113/how-to-format-datetime-columns-in-datagridview

Comment: It worked for changing the format, which is nice... but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

change the data type to datetime2 at SQL side (sorry for that short answer, can't make comments)

Comment: Tried that and.... "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"  :/

Comment: @hrutk1ta as was said previously, I guess the value from the column is not what you expect, try debugging and find out what the value type and value are

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass string value instead,  parameters will figure out the correct data type example `qlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@duedate", row.Cells[3].Value.ToString())`

Comment: "NullReferenceException was unhandled" for that line.... "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"   :(