# How to make a date column in a gridview not show timestamp when edited

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, gridview, timestamp

I have searched and searched and have not found a clear answer for this issue:

> When I set a column as a date column in a GridView and go into the grid and edit a date, it by default leaves a generic TimeStamp after the date like this (`09/12/2017 00:00:00`).

How do I remove the TimeStamp?

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033113/how-to-format-datetime-columns-in-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have formatting string like this (`{0:d}`) and have set apply format in edit mode true like this (`ApplyFormatInEditMode="true"`).

And implement to **BoundField** like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DataDate" ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}" 
     SortExpression="DataDate" HeaderText="Header Date" />
```