# How to show only date rather than datetime in data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6, datasource, bindingsource

So, I have this binding source:

```
 List<archive> list = _context.archive.Include(t => t.partner1).Include(t => t.partner).Include(t => t.document_type).ToList();

 list = list.OrderBy(d => d.issuing_date).ToList();
 BindingList<archive> bindingList = new BindingList<archive>(list);

this._view.ArchivekDatasource.DataSource = bindingList;
this._view.DocumentTypeDatasource.DataSource = _context.document_type.Local.ToBindingList();
this._view.PartnerDatasource.DataSource = _context.partner.Local.ToBindingList();
```

So, archive has two fields that are represented as datetime in the database. But I just want to have them as date when shown in data grid view... How can I do this?

I know there is the [truncate_time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.truncatetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Objects_EntityFunctions_TruncateTime_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__) function, but I don't know how to use it to create a binding source as I want.

Comment: I believe this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033113/how-to-format-datetime-columns-in-datagridview).

Comment: @s.m. Somehow it didn't work. I tried to set it before setting an actually datasource.

Comment: If you define your columns beforehand, use a `CellTemplate.ValueType` of type `DateTime` with `.Style = new DefaultCellStyle() { Format = "MM/dd/yyyy"}`. If not, after bindind the list, `dataGridView1.Columns[<SomeColumn>].CellTemplate.ValueType = typeof(DateTime);` `dataGridView1.Columns[<SomeColumn>].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
list = list.OrderBy(d => String.Format("{0:MM dd YYYY}", d.issuing_date)).ToList();
```

Maybe it can help.

Comment: What I did is ` list = list.OrderBy(d => String.Format("{0:mm:dd:yyyy}", d.issuing_date)).ToList();` and there was no change. I changed only single quotes to double quotes from your example.