# How to get rid of time when export datagridview into excel file VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

hello guys i got question about how to get rid of time at the back of date when exporting data list in datagridview using vb.net

here picture

[image]

this is date in datagridview which is no time at all

[image]

but after exporting the data become datetime..same goes to export into pdf..still have time..

```
   Private Sub tsbtnExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbtnExcel.Click
    With SaveFileDialog1

    End With
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim filename As String
        filename = SaveFileDialog1.FileName

        Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

        'Export Header Names Start
        Dim columnsCount As Integer = DataGridView1.Columns.Count
        For k As Integer = 1 To columnsCount
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
        Next
        'Export Header Name End

        'Export Each Row Start
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim checkselect As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells("chkCheck").Value)
            If checkselect = 1 Then
                For columnIndex As Integer = 1 To columnsCount - 1
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, columnIndex + 1).Value = row.Cells(columnIndex).Value.ToString
                Next
                i += 1
            End If
        Next
        'Export Each Row End
        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(filename + ".csv")
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
        MessageBox.Show("Export excel file successfully",
                        "Information",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Canceled, Export data failed",
                        "Information",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If

End Sub
```

this is the coding for exporting data into excel..and i use checkbox datagridview so that i can choose which i one to export..so i hope u guy can help me get rid the time when exporting into excel

Comment: The field is a DateTime so does contain the time, even if only 00:00. In your DataGridView you have chosen to format it so it displays as a date without the time (proably dd/MM//yyy), so do the same in the spreadsheet and format the column to display as date only. Or, as you are writing it as a string, check if it's a Date Value then format the string so it's Date only.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-format-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @JonRoberts i kinda not understand what you mean..im new with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it `xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, columnIndex + 1).Value = row.Cells(columnIndex).Value.ToString1` this coding suppose to be `xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, columnIndex + 1).Value = row.Cells(columnIndex).Value` ... the `ToString` take date with time when exporting DGV into excel

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to just convert your date into a string in the gridview.

```
date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

So the import will see those two columns as simple strings.

Or else

```
dataGridView1.Columns(12).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Assuming 12 is the index of the column you want to edit

Comment: do i need write the code in load or export button?

Comment: i write this code
`datagridview1.columns(12).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` but error occur

Comment: what type is your column(12) accepting? Cause the ideal would be to pass the date.Tostring to the gridview. It goes to error because you are trying to do a cast on all the dates into a single date format (you are selecting the column with all the dates inside it and trying to convert that array of Dates into a string with format "dd/MM/yyyy"), while you should try to convert one date at time.

Comment: if you can, post your code when you populate the gridview.

Comment: i edited the answer, check also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033113/how-to-format-datetime-columns-in-datagridview
it seems the issue is the same

Comment: ..column 12 and 13 suppose to be date in SQL Server so i thought column 12 and 13 will be date 

`Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Server=" + lblHost.Text + ";Database=PHMStaffList;User ID = ;password = ")`
        `conn.Open()`
        `Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MasterStaffList", conn)`
        
        `Dim table As New DataTable()`

        `adapter.Fill(table)`

        `DataGridView1.DataSource = table`

Comment: ..this is how i load datagridview from sql server... the column data type should be same with sql server

Comment: `dataGridView1.Columns(12).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"`

this coding just change format for datagridview when load the form...but when i try export it into excel still have the time